# lightning component to open url in new tab on button click

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, salesforce1-app

Can we open the component in a new url on button click?

fileUpload is another component that has to be opened in a different tab.

```
 <ui:button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral cuf-publisherShareButton qe-textPostDesktop WIDE uiButton--default uiButton--brand uiButton" 
          label="Click to Upload File" press="{!c.gotoURL}"  />

 gotoURL : function (component, event, helper) {
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
        "url": "skbteqforce:fileUpload"
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [navigateToComponent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToComponent.htm) is more suitable than navigateToURL:

```
navigateToMyComponent : function(component, event, helper) {
    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
    evt.setParams({
        componentDef : "c:myComponent",
        componentAttributes: {
            contactName : component.get("v.contact.Name")
        }
    });
    evt.fire();
}
```